# Can anyone assist me to read the details of the number 102 birth record of William Howes (Villiam Hoves )?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, denmark, genealogical-societies, genealogy-community

[enter link description here](https://media.geni.com/p14/de/0c/26/41/534448642e7e9a9f/william_original.jpg?hash=a202cdcd696474bf54930f64fc8c329b31685d47430c953417681c1e9b19b0e7.1697525999)Can anyone assist me to read the details of the number 102 birth record of William Howes (Villiam Hoves ) ?

24 July 1858

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is What I Got:

> **Name:** William Howes
> **Birth Date:** Oct 17 1858
> **Relatives:** William Howes,?, ?, Janette Yerl Morig